# PuTTY crashes on exit and requires computer reboot

Tags: windows-7, ssh, crash, putty, ssh-tunnel

PuTTY crashes when the program tries to exit. When it crashes, the window will freeze and will not close no matter what. Force close will not work, the task manager will not work. `pskill` from pstools (using administrator command prompt) has no effect-- it says the process has been killed, but it remains. Nothing will make the window go away except for a computer reboot.

This has been happening for a few weeks, possibly caused by a recent Windows update, but that's just a guess. It doesn't happen every time, but maybe 50% of the time. It crashes whether it is a manual exit invoked by typing "exit" or "logout", or when it exits itself because the computer has gone to sleep.

**It only happens when I use port tunneling.** I always have several PuTTY windows open, and the only one that crashes is the one with a port tunnel open.

Before the most recent crash, I opened the PuTTY log to see what it said. The final line was "Server sent command exit status 0", which seems normal.

[image: server exit status 0]

Here is a screenshot of my port tunnelling settings, in case that's relevant:

[image: port tunnel D9090]

Here is the Windows error box, which identifies the type of error as "AppHangB1":

[image]

Google has given me zero results. Searches for this type of crash have told me that it's often caused by a buggy driver, so that's one possible avenue, if anyone knows what I should try to update/roll back.

I updated PuTTY to the most recent version to no effect. I have not tried updating the remote computer (which I control) or my router, but I'd hope that neither of them are related to this kind of crash, which seems related to Windows itself.

Windows 7

---

## Update

I ran the debugging tools suggested, which generated a memory dump and an analysis of it. It's quite a lot of information, so I pasted into a [jsfiddle you can see here](https://jsfiddle.net/countytime/3ytq8f7d/show). I quoted the summary below, but please see that page for the full report, because it's quite a lot of information.

> **Description:** Detected possible blocking or leaked critical section at 0x041916d8 owned by thread 0 in
> putty.exe__PID__7768__Date__08_14_2018__Time_02_26_52PM__311__Manual
> Dump.dmp
>
> Impact of this lock: 25.00% of threads blocked (Threads 2)
>
> The following functions are trying to enter this critical section
>
> **mswsock!SockAsyncSelectCompletion+2a**
>
> The following module(s) are involved with this critical section:
>
> **C:\WINDOWS\System32\mswsock.dll** from Microsoft Corporation

---

## Update 3 weeks later

It has been nearly a month without a crash, and in that time there has been another Windows update. The timing is too coincidental; I think this must have been caused by a Windows update in the summer, probably July, and fixed in the August update.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling the [most recent version](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html) of PuTTY _(not upgrade, but actually uninstall, reboot, re-install)_?  If so, have you tried the [Snapshot version](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/snapshot.html)?  Have you filed a [Bug Report](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/feedback.html) on PuTTY's site?

Comment: Try to type `enter ~.` (enter-tilde-dot) before entering `exit` or when PuTTY is hang. Questions: How exactly are you exiting PuTTY and do you use the `exit` command? What is your MTU on both sides?

Comment: @harrymc: The crash happens whether I type `exit`, `logout`, or when PuTTY closes on its own because the computer goes to sleep. Typically I use `exit`. I don't know what my MTU is; I'm not familiar with the term. `enter ~.` is not a command recognized by the server,

Comment: While I'm not all that familiar with port tunneling, is there anything on the "other end" that is relying on the connection that you sever when you issue the "exit" or "logout" command? Maybe putty is encountering an error because when you exit the client from the putty POV, the "other end" is trying to recconect which causes an issue. (Just a thought as I work with putty, just not port tunneling.) Also just for clarification by port tunneling to you mean port forwarding?

Comment: I suggested the combination of `enter ~.` since it's used by ssh to locally drop the connection. It's evident that the local putty is hung on the connection, probably because the other side isn't correctly closing it. Could you please tell us which software is on the other side and what version are both sides.

Comment: Suggestion: In the configuration settings, try to change the setting of "Close window on exit". You may also try an alternative : [KiTTY](http://www.9bis.net/kitty/), [MobaXterm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/features.html), [Bitvise](https://www.bitvise.com/ssh-client).

Comment: I assume you using tunnel as SOCKS according to your screenshots. Did you close application that use tunnel (browser)  before you exiting? Do you use some antivirus ?

Comment: @Alex Yes, I close the browser before exiting (Firefox). When PuTTY closes because the computer went to sleep, Firefox has been closed for at least an hour at that point, so I don't think it could still be using a connection.

Comment: @harrymc According to the PuTTY log, it's `Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.10`. Is that what you're looking for? Interestingly, the next line is `We believe remote version has SSH-2 channel request bug`. Here is a screenshot (which unfortunately cuts off the ends of the sentences): https://i.imgur.com/lGRwcZe.png

Comment: Since you're connecting to a Linux server, you should also try exiting via `Ctrl+D`, as this acts as EOF in Linux and thus the connection will be severed.

Comment: I would also recommend that you try with KiTTY as well, as it's a fork of PuTTY.

Comment: See also: This known PuTTY bug, which may or may not be related... [unclean-close-crash: Reports of crashes on unclean close (related to port forwarding?)](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/unclean-close-crash.html)

Comment: @JW0914, I tried uninstalling, rebooting, and reinstalling, and was getting hopeful because there had been no crash for a couple days, but then it happened again last night.

Comment: @JW0914, when I reinstalled PuTTY, I noticed that it still had my old settings, which I think means that its registry values were not uninstalled. Is there a way to uninstall it including its registry values? (Or does that not matter? I'm trying everything I can think of.)

Comment: @RickwhoPrograms I actually don't know the difference between port forwarding and tunneling very well. I followed a guide to using Firefox through a proxy server. I first connect to the server with PuTTY, using the settings in the screenshot above (Connection/SSH/tunnels tab, port 9090 dynamic, or D9090). Firefox then uses this connection with its proxy settings, which are SOCKS host 127.0.0.1, port 9090. Here is a screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/0Wqb6zR.png

Comment: @felwithe All the PuTTY registry values contain are your saved profiles, Session Jumplists, and saved Host public keys... Registry location: `HKCU\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY`.  If you believe you've changed the default profile settings, and want to reset the default profile to default, then delete any keys within`Sessions` containing "default" in the key name.  I'd also recommend filing a [bug report](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/feedback.html) on PuTTY's site.

Comment: @felwithe Do you have any third-party firewall or virus-checking software installed? This behaviour sounds like something trying to hook network connections in the kernel but not handling this case well...

Comment: @Anon 4 Only Malwarebytes.

Comment: @felwithe If you temporarily disable Malwarebytes does the problem get any better?

Comment: There certainly are people whom know more about Windows debugging than I do but ... It's stuck at "ws2_32!closesocket+cd" called from: "putty+a1050" - notice that the 'putty+....." has no Function name, you would want to compile Putty **with** debugging symbols so that you are told the Function name and Line number. It ***looks*** like you have a call to close a Socket, and it's not returning. Without the Source it's a guess what the problem is. If you're a wiz at asm language and Window's calls you can load Putty.exe into the debugger and look at the code leading up to the call at   
a1050 .

Answer (score 2):

In the configuration settings of PuTTY, the setting of "Close window on exit"
may take part in the problem, so try to test its other available
settings.

You may also try an alternative free product, one of :
[KiTTY](http://www.9bis.net/kitty/),
[MobaXterm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/features.html), or
[Bitvise](https://www.bitvise.com/ssh-client).

If one of the alternatives works for you, then first you have a workaround for
the problem. Second, the problem itself is then probably some difficulty
in the communication protocol of PuTTY with the remote computer, and
you should report the problem to the developers.

However, if none of the alternatives works for you, then the problem is
probably not on your side. You should examine the setup of the SSH
server on the remote computer, try to debug it, and post here the trace logs
if you would like us to have a look.
If you do not have control of the remote computer, report the problem to its
administrator.

Comment: could a server trying to reconnect to his putty session be causing the issue as mentioned a few times now? That is my hunch but as I don't work much with port tunneling (forwarding?) I'm not sure. Also if that is the case what would the potential workaround be? Would there be any way to force the "retry connection" to stop if the host goes down from the remote side?

Comment: Not enough information on your setup to answer (and not sure I could even then). My guess would be that PuTTY is hanging while waiting for the server to acknowledge the close-connection request, and that the problem is a racing condition, one of the sides using a wrong timeout. This may explain why the problem is intermittent - the server may have closed the connection on his side, just that PuTTY missed out on that, waiting on an answer that never arrives and a closed connection. In TCP, closing the socket on one side is not reported to the other, so one has to depend on the protocol.

Comment: PuTTY might also be confused by the tunnel, so the tunnel itself may be preventing the closing of the connection to the server.

Comment: The SSH-2 channel request bug message might indicate the return of [this bug](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/ssh-close-vs-request.html) to your PuTTY version or in the server. In any case, you are surely encountering a software bug that is none of your doing. I suggest to ensure you are using the latest update on the server, then try some of the alternative clients I have listed above, doing the analysis as I have outlined in my answer.

Comment: I may try KiTTY as an absolute last resort, but I'd rather not, because PuTTY has worked for me for so long. This problem just started out of nowhere less than a month ago. PuTTY hasn't even changed in a year, so I think the problem obviously must be in my system somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

> PuTTY crashes on exit and requires computer reboot
>
> PuTTY crashes when the program tries to exit. When it crashes, the window will freeze and will not close no matter what. Force close will not work, the task manager will not work. pskill from pstools (using administrator command prompt) has no effect-- it says the process has been killed, but it remains. Nothing will make the window go away except for a computer reboot

I call that a "hang" and not a "crash". Crash means that **execution continues** either returning an error message (nice) or in the case of severe memory corruption there will be a pause (usually short, sometimes somewhat lengthy, rarely a watchdog) and execution will continue with a BSOD or reboot (not nice).

With a "hang" **no amount of time waited will seem to further your progress**, though other threads may continue to run normally if your Task Switcher is not affected and can switch to them.

Quite possibly what has happened is that PuTTY has spawned a VPN subroutine in order to tunnel, and *that* process has a problem; it has not returned to PuTTY and so PuTTY is hung.

The other process could have a temporary file open or a Port; termination of PuTTY ***might*** well close the subroutine but probably not remove any lock on files or ports from subprograms.

**How to find out for certain** - What is going on?

Reading a Microsoft Community webpage about that error titled: "[Windows Explorer 7 is not responding - 'apphangb1 explorer.exe' error](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/windows-explorer-7-is-not-responding-apphangb1/3334f101-2178-4661-977a-9c10d1cf8fd2)" it says:

> "**Andre.Ziegler**
>
> Create a hang dump of the Windows Explorer:
>
> http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/130005-creating-memory-dumps/
>
> compress the crash dump as 7z or RAR and upload it to your SkyDrive and post the link here.

Create the dump but you can analyze it yourself, or after searching all the SE sites for a duplicate question ask us: "How do I work with a .DMP file?".

Following that link to the webpage: "[Creating memory dumps](https://msfn.org/board/topic/130005-creating-memory-dumps/)" it says:

> "**Memory dump from an application/process that is HANGING (not crashing):**
>
> 1. Create a directory called c:\adplus
> 2. Open a command prompt and change to the directory where you installed the debugging tools. By default, this is "C:\Program Files\Debugging Tools for Windows"
> 3. Type the following command in the command prompt:
>
> `cscript adplus.vbs -hang -pn appname -quiet -o c:\adplus`
>
> (where "appname" is the .exe name of the application that is hanging)
>
> 4. Once the debugger has finished (this can take some time), the command prompt window(s) will close, and you will have data in your C:\adplus folder that can be analyzed.
>
> **Memory dump from an application/process that is CRASHING (not hanging):**
>
> 1. Create a directory called c:\adplus
> 2. Open a command prompt and change to the directory where you installed the debugging tools. By default, this is "C:\Program Files\Debugging Tools for Windows"
> 3. Type the following command in the command prompt:
>
> `cscript adplus.vbs -crash -pn appname -quiet -o c:\adplus`
>
> (where "appname" is the .exe name of the application that is crashing)
>
> 4. Once the application you have attached to in step 3 eventually crashes, the debugger will create a .dmp file (or files) of the process. Once the debugger has finished (this can take some time), the command prompt window(s) will close, and you will have data in your C:\adplus folder that can be analyzed.

See this Microsoft Support webpage: "[Debug Diagnostics Tool v1.2 is now available](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/2580960/debug-diagnostics-tool-v1-2-is-now-available)" where it describes usage of the DebugDiag tool.

It discusses:

> - Generating Memory Dumps:
>
>   - Process Crashes
>   - Process Hangs or Slow Performance

> To debug a process hang, or slow performance use one of the following:
>
> 1. Create a performance rule.   The performance rule could be based on Performance Counters or HTTP Response Times. This latter is specific to web servers or HTTP-based web services. The Performance Counters rule allows you to capture a series of consecutive userdumps when one or more Performance Counters exceed specified thresholds.   The HTTP Response Times  rule allows you to either use ETW (specific to IIS web server) or WinHTTP (to ‘ping’ any type of web server or HTTP-based web service) to capture userdumps when the configured timeout is reached.
> 2. Create a manual memory dump series during the slow or hang state by right-clicking the process name in the processes view and choosing the “Create Dump Series” option.
>
>    Then, analyze the resulting .dmp files with CrashHangAnalysis.asp and/or PerfAnalysis.asp (see below).
>
>    - Memory or Handle Usage

> - Analyzing Memory Dumps:
>
>   One of the most powerful features of DebugDiag is the ability to analyze memory dumps and generate a report file showing the analysis, along with recommendations to resolve identified problems.
>
>   DebugDiag uses “Analysis Scripts” to analyze memory dumps. There are 5 analysis scripts shipped with DebugDiag 1.2 as follows:
>
>   - Crash/Hang Analyzers - CrashHangAnalysis.asp
>   - Memory Pressure Analyzers - DotNetMemoryAnalysis-BETA.asp
>   - Memory Pressure Analyzers - MemoryAnalysis.asp
>   - Performance Analyzers - PerfAnalysis.asp
>   - SharePoint Analyzers    - SharePointAnalysis.asp".

Whatever the problem you can locate the exact point and find out which process is at fault and debug it. If you have a question about the use of those tools feel free to check for and ask a new question.

Comment: Ok, I got a crash analyses that looks like it might point to `mswsock.dll`. I will add it to the question since there's not enough room in the comment section.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may be having an issue with winsock filters, and your application is locking up on some sort of driver/IO issue.

In an administrative command prompt try: `netsh winsock reset` then reboot, and see if that makes a difference.

Off of the top of my head here are some other things to try:

- Remove any unused VPN software.
- Uninstall (and reinstall) the driver for your network card.
- Update the driver for your network card.
- If you have recently uninstalled an antivirus product, it is possible that network filter drivers have been left behind. If so you may want to find the removal tool for the appropriate security product and run it.

Answer (score -1):

Try running two scans:

## Scan 1

1. Run CMD as Administrator
2. Type `SFC /scannow` and press enter
3. When the scan is finished open `cbs.log` at `%windir%\logs\cbs\cbs.log`
4. Look for `cannot repair` and copy down the files that were not repaired.
5. Once you have located the files not repaired (if any), use your installation disk to access replacement file(s). Follow [these direction](http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/86959-access-vista-install-dvd-files.html) for getting replacement files(s).

## Scan 2 (Last Resort)

1. Run CMD as Administrator
2. Type `Chkdsk /f /r` and press enter
3. You will be shown a message regarding the volume to be locked. Press `y` and then enter.
4. Restart your computer
5. The scan will take a while. Wait for the scan to finish.
6. On reboot, go to `Event Viewer > Windows > Application Log` and then look for `Winninet`.
7. Look at the results of your scan.

I have found the answer at [Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/apphang-b1-problem-on-windows-7/9673992e-7c2a-42b1-b533-20c3abacb21d).

Comment: DON'T run `chkdsk /f /r` to test the disk as this may be destructive. Run first `chkdsk` and only if it has found errors, and only after having taken excellent backups, do the other. However, I don't think this is a disk error.